# Why am I getting "invalid read" and "invalid write" from valgrind with the following code?

Tags: c, linked-list, valgrind, singly-linked-list, cs50

I am writing a program to make sure I understand how to correctly implement a singly linked list in C. I'm currently in the middle of Harvard's CS50 course, and using this tutorial since the CS50 people don't explain the linked list data structure in a lot of detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Fz7JSvlr9g

The code seems to function ok, but I am getting "invalid read" and "invalid write" errors when I check it using valgrind.

Here's my code:

```
// creating and using a singly linked list in C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// create structure for nodes
typedef struct sllist
{
    int val;
    struct sllist *next;
}
sllnode;

// function declarations
sllnode *create(int sz);
void display(sllnode *head);

int main(void)
{
    // declare head node and set to NULL
    sllnode *head = NULL;

    // prompt for size of list
    printf("how many numbers would you like to store? ");
    int sz;
    scanf("%i", &sz);

    // create linked list (create passes head pointer back to head)
    head = create(sz);
    // display linked list
    display(head);
}

// function for creating a linked list
sllnode *create(int sz)
{
    // initialize head pointer to NULL
    sllnode *head = NULL;
    // initialize temp pointer (for creating new nodes in the upcoming for loop)
    sllnode *temp = NULL;
    // initialize p for iterating through the list
    sllnode *p = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
        // allocate space for individual node
        temp = (sllnode *)malloc(sizeof(sllnode));

        // check to make sure we haven't run out of memory
        if (temp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Couldn't allocate memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // prompt user for value to store
        printf("enter the value #%i: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%i", &(temp->val));

        // intialize temp's next pointer to NULL
        temp->next = NULL;

        // if running first time (linked list is empty) temp becomes the head node
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        // if the loop has run a few times (list not empty)
        else
        {
            // start at the head
            p = head;
            // iterate through the list to find the last node
            while (p->next != NULL)
            {
                p = p->next;
            }
            // set that node's pointer to the new node
            p->next = temp;
        }
        free(temp);
    }
    // give the head pointer back to main
    return head;
}

// function for displaying the linked list
void display(sllnode *head)
{
    // initialize pointer p to head (coming from main)
    sllnode *p = head;

    // iterate through the list, printing a new value each time
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%i -> ", p->val);
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And here's the output from valgrind:

```
==4407== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4407== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4407== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4407== Command: ./ll0
==4407== 
how many numbers would you like to store? 2
enter the value #1: 1
enter the value #2: 6
==4407== Invalid read of size 8
==4407==    at 0x4209DA: create (ll0.c:74)
==4407==    by 0x420713: main (ll0.c:29)
==4407==  Address 0x6183048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==4407==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4407==    by 0x420B73: create (ll0.c:81)
==4407==    by 0x420713: main (ll0.c:29)
==4407== 
==4407== Invalid write of size 8
==4407==    at 0x420B65: create (ll0.c:79)
==4407==    by 0x420713: main (ll0.c:29)
==4407==  Address 0x6183048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==4407==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4407==    by 0x420B73: create (ll0.c:81)
==4407==    by 0x420713: main (ll0.c:29)
==4407== 
==4407== Invalid read of size 4
==4407==    at 0x420CAA: display (ll0.c:96)
==4407==    by 0x420720: main (ll0.c:31)
==4407==  Address 0x6183040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==4407==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4407==    by 0x420B73: create (ll0.c:81)
==4407==    by 0x420713: main (ll0.c:29)
==4407== 
1 -> ==4407== Invalid read of size 8
==4407==    at 0x420D62: display (ll0.c:97)
==4407==    by 0x420720: main (ll0.c:31)
==4407==  Address 0x6183048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==4407==    at 0x4C2BDEC: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4407==    by 0x420B73: create (ll0.c:81)
==4407==    by 0x420713: main (ll0.c:29)
==4407== 
6 -> 
==4407== 
==4407== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4407==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4407==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==4407== 
==4407== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==4407== 
==4407== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4407== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Seems like it has something to do with the way I'm accessing the temp node, but I don't really understand the issue.

Comment: you cannot do `free(temp);` inside the create function. You have to do it after you're done using the list.

Comment: In order to debug this, you should really separate creation of nodes with reading user input.

Comment: @SouravGhosh As far as I know, the temp variable disappears once the function call is over -- should I then pass that pointer back to main and then free it?

Comment: @Broman What would you say is the advantage of separating the two? I suppose the user prompts could stay in the main function, and each time the user is asked for input, the create function would be called, but it seems like a lot of unnecessary back and forth between the two functions... What is the disadvantage of asking for user input within the create function, once it's been passed the size of the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the `create` function you free the nodes you just have added to the list.

Simply remove the `free(temp);` from the function.

The variable name `temp` is misleading here. It is not at all a temporary node. A correct name for this variable would be `newnode`.

You should read again the chapter dealing with dynamic memory allocation in your C text book.

---

**Note 1:** BTW: In the video you mention there is no `free` in the `create` function.

---

**Note 2:** Be aware that this algorithm for creating the list is terribly inefficient. In order to find the last element, the whole list is traverses from the head to the last element. In order to be efficient you should maintain the pointer to the last element.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! Removing free(temp) (or now free(newnode)) results in a memory leak though... Any suggestions?

==2349== 48 (16 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==2349==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2349==    by 0x420724: create (ll0.c:47)
==2349==    by 0x4206C3: main (ll0.c:29)

Comment: @Matvey of course you have a memory leak now. In your buggy code you freed the memory too early, now you don't free it at all. You need to write a function that frees all nodes of the list. Hint: this function is very similar to the `display` function. I leave this as an exercise to you.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. I followed your advice and wrote a freememory function, and now it's working properly with no memory leaks! Do you know if it's customary to update questions with corrected code? I'm hesitant because then I might as well delete the whole question :)

Comment: No, leave the question as it is.